# Reject promise in the chain

Tags: angularjs, promise

So this may be trivial, but I am doing some proof of concept stuff and trying to reject a promise in the middle of a promise chain, but I am not getting the results I would expect.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $q) {
    var def = $q.defer();

    def.promise
    .then(testPromiseReject())
    .then(
      function(){
        console.log("SUCCESS")
      }, 
      function(){
        console.log("FAIL")
      });

    def.resolve();

    function testPromiseReject(action)
    {
      return $q.reject()
    }
  });
```

I think I am creating a promise that I initially resolve, but in the first `then` I have a function that I am trying to reject the rest of the promise chain. The above code prints `"SUCCESS"` to the console. Why is it not rejecting the rest of the chain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a problem with this line...

```
.then(testPromiseReject())
```

It just needs the `()`s removed so it's not executed immediately...

```
.then(testPromiseReject)
```

Fiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/5LVEE/1/